# How to get HTML image tag attribute value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I have this HTML code:

```html
<img src="../../../media/test.jpg" alt="test" />
```

But want only this:

```rb
"../../../media/test.jpg"
```

How can I get this in Ruby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/)

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse <<-end
<img src="../../../media/test.jpg" alt="test" />
end
node = doc.at_css('img')
# => #(Element:0x49a28e8 {
#      name = "img",
#      attributes = [
#        #(Attr:0x49a2da2 { name = "src", value = "../../../media/test.jpg" }),
#        #(Attr:0x49a2e24 { name = "alt", value = "test" })]
#      })
node.attributes 
# => {"src"=>
#      #(Attr:0x50324ba { name = "src", value = "../../../media/test.jpg" }),
#     "alt"=>#(Attr:0x50324b0 { name = "alt", value = "test" })}
node.keys
# => ["src", "alt"]
node.values
# => ["../../../media/test.jpg", "test"]
node['src']
# => "../../../media/test.jpg"
node['alt']
# => "test"
```

If you want to delete attribute `alt` you can do the below :

```
node.delete('alt')
node
# => #(Element:0x49a28e8 {
#      name = "img",
#      attributes = [
#        #(Attr:0x49a2da2 { name = "src", value = "../../../media/test.jpg" })]
#      })
node.values
# => ["../../../media/test.jpg"]
```

Comment: To actually get the answer, I think you want `node['src']`. That will return `"../../../media/test.jpg"`.

Comment: that's done.. it was not copied from my editor.. I don't know why :(( I did it now..

Comment: @RoryO'Kane great edit.. I have ever seen in the OP's post.. Nice :))

Comment: t returns array then.. What to do..??

Comment: @AshekurRahmanMollaAsik Yes, `node.values` returns an array, but that's not the final answer. Priti showed that you can get the answer directly, not in an array, with `node['src']`. Also, you should know that to get the first item in a Ruby array, you use `theArray[0]` or `theArray.first`.

Comment: if I want to use 
http://localhost/test/test.php 
instead of
<img src="../../../media/test.jpg" alt="test" />
then what to do??

Comment: @AshekurRahmanMollaAsik so what? I answered your need. If any more question you have,please post a different questions.. you will get your answer.. that url is not being opened.

Answer (score 3):

Us the nokogiri gem.

http://nokogiri.org/

```
   require 'nokogiri'
   require 'open-uri'

   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://google.com"))
   images_you_want = doc.css("div#lga img").map{|links| links['src']}

   >images_you_want
   =>["/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png"]
```